# Retrieving value from a select tag in asp.net from controller to view

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an asp.net webapp, and in a view I have a drop down list that the user can select a value from. The drop down list works just fine-the right text is displayed in the menu. But, when I try and use some basic JS to capture the value, I get 
"Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'GetElementById' " in the JS Console in Chrome. Here is  my code:

```
<select id="stop" onchange="sendInfo();">

@foreach(var blah in ViewBag.foobar)
{


<option value=@blah>@blah</option>

}
</select>

<script>
function sendInfo() {

    var stopId = document.GetElementById("stop").value;

}

</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated, I am very new to MVC and asp.net stuff.

Thanks,

Amanda

Comment: It's getElementById, not GetElementById. Also, you might consider using jQuery, it will be diffidult at first but it will make your life a LOT easier in the long run. Getting a tag's value with jQuery: $("#stop").val();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is a case sensitive language and the method what your are looking for is [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById)

So you should write:

```
var stopId = document.getElementById("stop").value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `getElementById` function, you can access html element by event object which passed to each event handler:

```
<select id="stop" onchange="sendInfo(event);">

@foreach(var blah in ViewBag.foobar)
{
     <option value=@blah>@blah</option>
}
</select>

<script>
function sendInfo(event) {
        var stopId = event.target.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById...`

Case sensitivity matters.